# Javascript getting property value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My problem is:

Works:

`console.log(variable[apple]);`

```
variable: {
  apple : "xxx"
}
```

Not working:

`console.log(variable.element[apple]);`

```
variable: {
  element: {
    apple: "xxx"
  }
}
```

`element` is not undefined. 
Any idea?

Comment: This `req.body` should be syntax error. Also `[apple]` should be in quotes

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)."_

Comment: this req.body is just an example... but okay, I change the variable names

Comment: `console.log(variable.element.apple);`

Comment: @HowToTellForAChild Use **@** to tag a user

Comment: what about tell us your complete code,code above get errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Dear Andreas!
My desired behaviour is to wok this statement:
console.log(variable.element[apple]);
My specific problem is: This statement above is not working!
You don't help in my problem, if you just insert quotations.

Comment: And your "question" doesn't help us to help you, hence the link on how to create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: @Andreas if you want to really help me, or to others, then ask, if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable: {  //this is a code block labeled "variable"
  element: {  //this is a code block labeled "element"
    apple: "xxx"  //this is an expression "xxx" labeled as "apple"
  }
}
```

But there's no variable in your code. Read up about [labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

You probably mean

```
var variable = {  //now this is a variable containing an object
  element: {  //and these are properties of that object
    apple: "xxx"  
  }
}

console.log(variable.element.apple);
```